# Reading <textarea> changed Height

Tags: textarea

I am using a  for data entry in asp.net core application 
the Height of the textarea can be changed manually by the user  , I want to read the new height in order to save it in the database at server side . My problem is reading that value .
using Javascript with style.width  will return the original value not the new changed value

Can anyone give me a clue .

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,
HTML:

```
<textarea id="yourinputid"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
let areaHeight=$('#yourinputid').height();
```

On:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
    $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
};
```

});